# simulating memory usage in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

Is there any Java api available which would help in simulating a fixed amount of memory being used ??

I am building a dummy application that contains no implementations in its methods. All i would like to do within this methods is simulate a certain amount of memory being used up - is this at all possible?

Comment: static byte[] dummy = new byte[desired_size]; ?

Comment: `new byte[AMOUNT]` ... but that's relatively pointless. What benefit do you expect to get from this?

Comment: You have `ByteBuffer.allocate()`, for instance -- but `new byte[]` has less overhead

Comment: Thanks for your answers -- it didn't occur to me that this was all i needed.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to consume a fixed amount of memory is to create a byte array of that size and retain it.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1000*1000]; // use 1 MB of memory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Could get tricky with the way Java handles memory, considering applications are run through the runtime environment, don't know if it's going to the heap, etc.

One simple way might be loading text files into memory of the specific sizes you want, then somehow making sure they don't get garbage collected once the method returns.